# Access bcache backing data without bcache (eg from Windows)

Tags: windows, bcache

Assuming that the `bcache` cache device is fully flushed, is it possible to access the data stored in a `bcache` backing device without `bcache`?

I'd like to have a `bcache` NTFS partition which is also accessible from Windows dual boot system.

Answer (score 1):

[`bcache.txt`](https://source.puri.sm/Librem5/linux-emcraft/commit/c0b8c9a3447ad379869f21884b86ec97c7b8db7a?expanded=1#63493b7f2c42aa351352e201496e9c7aa3950d10_180_176)
 says:

> **Recovering data without bcache:**
>
> If bcache is not available in the kernel, a filesystem on the backing
>   device is still available at an 8KiB offset. So either via a loopdev
>   of the backing device created with `--offset 8K`, or any value defined by
>   `--data-offset` when you originally formatted bcache with `make-bcache`.

I see that `make-bcache` [has an option](https://helpmanual.io/help/make-bcache/):

```
-o, --data-offset   data offset in sectors
```

If this were set to be a (1M / sector size) offset, it should it then be possible to create an overlapping GPT partition starting +1M and ending at the same sector as the backing device.